# Kdenlive 480p rendering

Tags: kdenlive

I'm using kubuntu 20.04. also I'm using kdenlive for my video editing. I wanna render a video in low file size. i used to render in 480p in Premiere pro. How can I di that in kdenlive. Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, go to **Project > Project Settings** and then pick your resolution.

[image]